# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: wp-admin, 500-internal-error

I'm getting this 500 error in the browser:

> HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition
>   that prevented it from fulfilling the request. (XHR)POST -
>   https://www.example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Below is my code. This gets executed when I press the submit button. When the submit is clicked, this alert: `alert('!!!Submission Error!!!');` pops up followed by the above error on the console. I couldn't figure out what's happening. I have the same copy of the site in my staging environment, where it doesn't show any error.

```
$.ajax({
        url: jquery_main_data.ajaxurl,
        data : {
            action : jquery_main_data.action_form,
            fields : fields,
            nonce: jquery_main_data.nonce_form
        },
        type : 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function() {
            jQuery(".button.submit").text("Loading...");
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);

            if(response.is_valid == true) {
                    window.location.href = '/thank-you/';
            } else {
                alert('error....');
            }
        },
        always: function() {
            jQuery(".button.submit").text("Submit");
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            alert('!!!Submission Error!!!');
            jQuery(".button.submit").text("Submit");
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }

    });
```

Comment: JavaScript can’t cause a 500 error on its own. The problem will be in the PHP code you’re using on the back end. What’s that code?

Comment: Does https://www.example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php exist?

Comment: @mediaguru Yes that link does exist.

This issue got resolved by itself but I'm keen to learn how. When I tested the site after 5 hours, the site had already started working and receiving form submissions. The web host said they didn't fix anything on their end. I noticed the issue after I updated WP and some plugins. But how did it fix by itself?

Comment: Maybe there was a cache issue which cleared when the cache cleared.